# Pop up alert yes/no , when using the answer to run PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, onclick, popup, dom-events

I want to run an SQL function of delete write in PHP throw `onclick` button.
I thought about asking yes/no popup save the answer in a variable and if `variable==ok`
run the SQL function, can someone help me?
This is the SQL query write on PHP:

```
function DeleteProduct($thisCatalog) {
    
    $connB = new ProductDAO();
    $connB->Connect();
    $pro_query = "DELETE * FROM Ikea WHERE `CatalogNumber` = $thisCatalog";
    $db_result = $connB->ExecSQL($pro_query);

    $html_result = 'Your Product Has Been Deleted! ';

    $connB->Disconnect();
    return $html_result;
}
```

This is the button of delete

```
<p align=center> <img src="pic/trash.png" title="Delete Product" onclick="conf();submit();">
```

Where to put the delete function call?

Comment: Insert it at line 132.   where are the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var answer = confirm("Delete?")
    if(answer) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "delete.php",
            type: "post",
            data: $('#yourForm').serialize(),
            error: function(data) {
                alert("There was an error while deleting from the database.");
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // do something
            });
        });
    }
    else {
        // do something
    }
});
```